# Can year 1 gear be upgraded to the same values as Taken King gear?

Tags: destiny

With the release of taken king I have binge played it for several hours and the one thing I noticed is that uncommon gear now outranks my legendaries and exotics. Now I'm a little annoyed by that considering how much time I spent acquiring that gear only to have it be declared lower tier. Not only that but I much prefer the look of my exotic equipment over the minimalist design of the new equipment. My question is, is there any way to upgrade my gear to match the same values that the taken king gear has? For instance, a similar way to the house of wolves' etheric light upgrades? Am I just better off getting accustomed to the new gear instead?

Comment: This is far from an exhaustive answer, so I'll leave it as a comment for now. Certain year 1 exotics have year 2 equivalents that can be crafted with an exotic shard and legendary marks, assuming you have the required blueprint (unlocked by obtaining the year 1 version). Presumably they can be acquired through engrams or nightfalls. As for an etheric light analog, I'm not aware of any.

Comment: I've seen the crafting system for exotics but what I'm unsure of is how do you acquire legendary marks? Are they obtainable in strikes?

Comment: Legendary marks are obtained from the new max level playlist. Your first three runs per week per account grant extra marks, and you receive extra rewards for staying in the playlist longer without returning to orbit (I don't have confirmation, but I assume this applies to the legendary marks as well). By default you earn 1 per strike in the new playlist. You can carry a maximum of 200 and there is **no limit to how many you can earn per week**.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

***No***

Equipment obtained in Year 1 will never be upgradeable beyond Year 1 maximums. The best you can hope for is that you might find a Year 2 version somewhere along the way.

Bungie did make Year 2 editions of some Year 1 gear, but most didn't make the cut. If you have a piece of gear from Year 1 that did fall into this category though, it still won't be able to go higher than the Year 1 caps. You'll have to find (or make) a Year 2 copy of that item if you want to upgrade.

Note that Infusing - a new mechanism by which gear and consumables can be sacrificed to boost stats on other gear - won't let you bypass this, either. There's two reasons it won't work:

1. Like Reforging in HoW, Infusing requires the target item to have a specific perk. Year 1 gear won't have it.
2. To perform Infusion, the sacrificed item and the target item must be of the same Year and the sacrificed item must have higher Attack/Defense stats.

Obviously, #1 is a killer on its own. But #2 also means that even if Year 1 items did have the perk, the best you could do is use Infusion to boost your gear up to Year 1 maximums anyway. After that, the highest Year 1 gear you'll have will have the same Attack/Defense as whatever you might want to combine with it for Infusion - rendering the combination ineligible.

Note that #2 also very well could imply that Year 2 gear will never be upgradeable to Year 3 stats, when that time comes. But that's a fairly long way from now in development terms, and a lot could change.